# Proof involved convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $ A $ is a nonempty closed subset of $ \mathbb R $ and $ (a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty $ is a sequence of numbers in $ A. $ Prove that if $ a_n $ converges to a number $ p, $ then $ p \in A. $

I attempted to apply the definition of limit as following:
$ a_n $ converges to $ p $ if for every $ \epsilon > 0, $ there exists $ N \geq 0 $ such that for every $ n > N, |a_n - p| < \epsilon, $ but I got stuck from there.

Comment: Define "closed."

Comment: If it converges to p then p is a limit point of the sequence and thus of A.  If A is closed what do you know about its limit points?

Comment: Now, you can assume as a contradiction that $p\in \Bbb R\setminus A$ and use the fact that $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda true that this can be viewed as a definition but one can get from the purely topological definition of a closure to the special case of a closed set in a metric space:

A subset $A \subset \mathbb R$ is closed if for every $x \in A$ you have 
$$B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \space (\forall \epsilon >0)$$

Since $a_n$ in $A$ converges to $p$ we have:
$ \forall \epsilon>0\space \exists n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \in B_{\epsilon}(p) \space (\forall n \geq n_0)$. Note that $a_n$ is in $A$ and hence we get $B_{\epsilon}(p)\cap A$ **non-empty** for all $\epsilon >0$. Therefore $p \in A$ as $A$ is closed.